# Create one trigger for all tables in a database

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I want to Create trigger on a database that would first check if similar trigger exist,if not it then create it.The For any insertion on any table in the database,it populate the DateCreated and DateModified Columns on that table.My current one is only doing it on one table. here is my code:

```
USE [Issue]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Update_DateCreated_DateModified]    Script Date: 04/11/2013 12:07:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Nyname>
-- Create date: <Create ,10-04-13,>
-- Description: <Description,Add DateCreate and DateModifid for last records inserted,>
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_DateCreated_DateModified]
ON  [dbo].[Patient] 
FOR  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @getDateCreated Datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @getDateModified DATETIME=GETDATE()
DECLARE @patient_nin VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT NIN FROM INSERTED i)

-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for trigger here
UPDATE dbo.Patient SET DateCreated=@getDateCreated,DateModified=@getDateModified


END

GO
```

Comment: What is the problem you have exactly? You need to create one trigger per table, so you could get a list of table names (e.g. by querying `sys.tables`) and then build your script. You can do it in TSQL (as shown `here`) or in a script in another language.

Comment: what i wanted is to loop through  all the tables in a database and create the trigger i post if it does exist in any table.This does not seem efficient performance wise, but it is a task delegated to me. i want to have it working first then try to convince my Boss that it may not be the best approach.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. If you want to add a trigger to each table, then you need to loop over those tables somehow, because `CREATE TRIGGER` creates one trigger on one table (for DML triggers). I don't think performance should be an issue because this is presumably a one-time task, although in future you should probably make it part of your development process, so that any new table always has the trigger on it.

Comment: @Pondlife that what i need was to loop through all tables in a db and create the trigger.But is done now.